# How to use a external application.properties file whith spring batch CommandLineJobRunner

Tags: spring-batch

I need to use a application.properties file to define a DataSource in a Spring Batch application.

When I execute the generated spring boot runnable jar, the application.properties in the resource folder is used correctly and the DataSource is created accordingly to the definition in application.properties.

But, when a use the CommandLineJobRunner class to run my job I get a dependency injection error because the spring could not find the DataSource bean.

I have tried to put the application.properties in the classpath, in the same folder where I am executing the CommandLineJobRunner and in a config folder. None of that have worked.

Comment: can you show some code and the actual error? The fact that you say the DataSource could not be find may have nothing to do with application.properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this one

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:/example.jdbc.properties" order="1" system-properties-mode="OVERRIDE"/>
```

For detail, please refer item #8 at the [link](https://bigzidane.wordpress.com/2016/09/06/spring-batch-maven-hibernate-oracle-and-intellij/)